# React/Firebase setState no updating

Tags: reactjs

I am running into an issue where a user submits an email address on a form. The email address is looked up in a firebase db...then tied to some additional data that will be pushed into an array. **Unfortunately, I am currently having to click the submit button twice in order to get the certificates to render correctly.** I have been looking at different bits of info regarding callbacks, etc. I've simplified the code that is running after the user clicks submit. Apologize if this is a repeat question...none of the info I found led me in the right direction. Just back to square one.

```
processEmail(e) {
var certs = [];


e.preventDefault();

Fire.database().ref().orderByChild('Email').equalTo(this.inputEl.value).on('value', function(snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.exists()) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

      var key = childSnapshot.key;


      certs.push(snapshot.child(key+"/Item").val());


  })

  } else {
    console.log('nope');
    alert("Looks like we can't find you.");
  }

})


this.setState({
  cert: certs
});
}
```

Comment: the `this.setState` should probably be called from inside the `if(snapshot.exists()){..}` block.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out. Thanks Gabriele for pointing me in the right direction. Here is some updated code for those that may find this useful in the future. Things to note...Couldn't use "this" inside the Firebase call so had to let updateState = this. Also, when pushing to an array, keep the array outside of the loop or it will just reset itself with a single value for each iteration. Easy enough.

```
processEmail(e) {

e.preventDefault();

let updateState = this;

Fire.database().ref().orderByChild('Email').equalTo(this.inputEl.value).on('value', function(snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.exists()) {
    var certs = [];
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {


      var key = childSnapshot.key;

      certs.push(snapshot.child(key+"/Item").val());

      first.push(snapshot.child(key+"/First Name").val());

      lastN.push(snapshot.child(key+"/Last Name").val());

      updateState.setState({
        cert: certs
      });


  })

  } else {
    console.log('nope');
    alert("Sorry! Looks like we can't find you.");
  }

})

}
```